# WatchKit: How to localize system-provided Dismiss button?

Tags: ios, localization, push-notification, watchkit, apple-watch

Notification interface has predefined Dismiss button, and I’m looking for the way to add localization for it.

[image]

Is there any way to do this? I haven’t found the answer in the docs.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Generally speaking, if it is predefined it should be handled by Apple.

Comment: Found some info on xamarin, Buttons have a Title property, which is reflected in the way their localized values are set: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/working-with/localization/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change title of Dismiss button by yourself - it is managed by iOS and will be localised according to language preferences on a device. Dismiss button will be always present on notification interface to dismiss/close the corresponding view and third-party developers can not influence on Dismiss button behaviour and style.

But you can add extra buttons on your notification with needed titles and actions - here is detailed manual by Apple itself: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1